# "exclude_matches" in manifest.json does nothing?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm having a problem controlling what pages my content scripts are injected into. The [chrome extension developer guide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) specifies that I can use an "exclude_matches" directive in my `manifest.json` to exclude certain pages from injection.

However, this doesn't seem to have any effect. My content script still executes on pages that I have specified as ignored.

I have put the [steps to reproduce in a Gist](https://gist.github.com/2029447). The code is also [available on Github](https://github.com/dtuite/chrome-ext-exclude-matches).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Testing Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Test the chrome extensions exclude_matches.",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "exclude_matches": ["http://news.ycombinator.com/"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }]
}
```

**content.js**

```
console.log("hello from the content script");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is [Bug #100106](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100106). `exclude_matches` do not function properly.

To solve the problem, use **`exclude_globs`** instead of `exclude_matches`.

Also, your `exclude_matches` rule does only match `http://news.ycombinator.com/`.
Suffice the pattern with an **asterisk** to match the whole site: `http://news.ycombinator.com/*`.

See also: [Match patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html).

Comment: Tried it right now and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I still see the log from the content script. In fact, I can set my `exclude_matches` directive to `["http://*/*"]` and the content script still executes on every http page.

Comment: @duckyfuzz I see. Weird. Using **`exclude_globs`** instead of `exclude_matches` solves the problem.

Comment: This still doesn't work for CSS files, as I asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784654/excluding-domains-from-content-scripts-in-manifest-json-doesnt-work-for-css-fil).