# Chrome extension content scripts injecting into images

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I feel stupid for asking this, but I can't for the life of me get this to work.

The gist of the problem: I have a chrome extension with a content script injected javascript popup UI that is embedded into loaded pages.  The user can click a button in the chrome extension bar and it opens.  Opens in this case means unhiding and displaying with a simplemodal popup. This all works great.

However, when I load up a JPG into the browser, like say just going here http://customersrock.files.wordpress.com/2007/07/bunny.jpg it still injects the content script information into the page.  **ONLY jpgs seem to be affected.**  PNGs and gifs are not (though I haven't done an extensive test of image formats).  However, since it's a JPG and not a full website, the content that's injected is not hidden.  It's unstyled and just kind of sitting there below the image, like such (please forgive the size of this image):

[image: Example problem]

My content script matching is as follows

```
 "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
 "exclude_matches":["*://*.png", "*://*.jpg", "*://*.gif"],
```

I'm honestly not even sure if the exclude matches are done correctly or really working at all to be honest.  Does chrome serve up jpgs in a different manner than other image formats?  Anyways, thanks for the help!  This is a frustrating problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Matching the MIME type (Content-Type) in Content Scripts is currently an open issue in Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35070  If it were fixed, you could match just HTML instead of trying to exclude every type by URL pattern or "extension".

Comment: Oh, well that certainly explains why it wasn't working when I tried it lol. That would make things a heck of a lot simpler.  Well, thanks for the info Robert!  I'll keep an eye on that bug, though it seems to be pretty old at this point x_x.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [“exclude_matches” in manifest.json does nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687322/exclude-matches-in-manifest-json-does-nothing) Short answer: this is a known bug; try using [`exclude_globs`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#match-patterns-globs) instead of `exclude_matches`. I'm not sure if it applies in your case, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a known bug, I got an alternate way to tackle this problem. Enclose your script in an `If statement` like this :

```
if (window.location.pathname.split('.jpg') < 1) {
    //
    // Your script here.
    //
}
```

This would however inject the script to the `jpg` page, but won't run the script in the `if statement`.