# Excluding domains from content_scripts in manifest.json doesn't work for CSS files?

Tags: css, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to write a chrome extension to force all websites to use given CSS style except Gmail page. However the following code from content scripts in `manifest.json` doesn't work (Gmail page will still use the style given in `font.css`).

```
"content_scripts":  [{
    "matches":  ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "exclude_matches": ["*://mail.google.com/*"],
    "css":  ["font.css"]
}]
```

This cannot be fixed even adopting the strategy advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687322/exclude-matches-in-manifest-json-does-nothing) by replacing <kbd>exclude_matches</kbd> with <kbd>exclude_globs</kbd>.

I know this bug existing for a while, so-called [Bug #100106](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100106). Any idea on how to fix this? Or are there any alternative ways I can use to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter pages manually if you inject CSS from some content JavaScript code. I've just did a quick test, and the following works in Chrome 31.0.1650.63:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Style",
    "description": "Insert custom CSS",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches":  ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "js": ["font.js"],
        "run_at":"document_start"
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["font.css"]
}
```

font.js

```
if (location.hostname.indexOf(".google.com") == -1) {
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.href = chrome.extension.getURL("font.css");
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    document.documentElement.insertBefore(link);
}
```

font.css

```
body {
    color: red;
}
```

This way font.css script is injected into all non-Google pages.

Comment: I tried your method. However, all websites have no effect now. What maybe the problem is?

Comment: I've edited my answer by attaching full source code, which works (tested in Google Chrome 31.0.1650.63). Please check whether you have some errors in console :)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One problem of this method is that, when loading one webpage, we can still see the original style (at first half second) and then switch to CSS style. Any idea on how to make it refresh faster?

Comment: To be more detail, compared with previous method (no `js`), using `js` as you answered will 1) need refreshing for pre-opened webpages and 2) need longer response time (as I said above, we can still see the original style (at first half second) and then switch to CSS style). Do you have any idea to make it better?

Comment: Please see my last edit, this version of JS is injected earlier, thus allowing earlier injection of CSS.