# Limit Chrome extension permission to part of address

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I created a Google Chrome extension that injects content scripts on two adresses:

1. `https://allegro.pl/listing*`
2. `https://allegro.pl/kategoria/*`

   and I declared these content scripts in the manifest.json file.

This works fine, and injects them there and nowhere else.

Unfortunately, when a user installs the extension, they get the message 'this extension can read and change all your data on **allegro.pl**'.
The problem is that it doesn't tell the user that I need access to only these 2 addresses , but tells them I need access to the entire domain.

Now, there is no sensitive data on the 2 adresses my extension is using - user passwords are entered elsewhere on the site. So I'd like my users to know that their passwords are safe and that the extension cannot read them.

Is there a way to do something about this?

Comment: Have you tried the URL(s) without the asterisk (*)...as  with the *, it may include all the url(s) started with https://allegro.pl/* .

Or you can use the exclude_globes to prevent a URL to execute the script. Check here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687322/exclude-matches-in-manifest-json-does-nothing

Comment: Permissions are granted per *origin*, in other words the entire site. This is how web same-origin access works: even if your script runs just on one URL it still can access the entire origin. Chrome can't limit that as it would break the basics of the web.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, so I guess I can't do anything about it. I don't think it would be unreasonable to think that Google Chrome would have its internal way of letting an extension only manipulate sites with a certain address - although clearly it doesn't have it. Also, I don't know what you mean that a script could access the entire origin? The script is only loaded on the specified adresses.

Comment: @Vishal thanks but the scripts are injected only where I specified - so that part works. It only displays the permission as having access to the entire site.

Comment: Regardless of the initial URL where your script is loaded, it can access the entire origin of that URL because this is the way the web works: cookies (mostly), localStorage, IndexedDB, WebSQL - all these things are accessible on the entire origin. This is why there's no point in limiting the permissions to paths, which incidentally also means your background script can insert another non-declared content script at any address in the URL origin.